# How can I make a scatterpie plot in which the colors of the pies are determined by the data?

Tags: python, r, plot

I have a data set of three variables: "A", "B" and "C". Each variable has a value range from 1 to 3. The pie then consists of three pieces, and we want each piece to have an equal size of 1/3, therefore we construct new variables "Apiece", "Bpiece" and "Cpiece", all having value 1 in each row. I would like to visualize the values of the variables A, B, and C by means of different colors in the pie chart. I want to use colors, because the colors would represent their absolute value rather than their relative value compared to the other categories.  For instance: values between 1 and 1.25 should be colored green, between 1.25 and 1.5 should be light-green, etc. To be precise, the ranges for the colors are as follows:

1    < x <= 1.4         Green

1.4  < x <= 1.8         Light-green

1.8  < x <= 2.2         Yellow

2.2  < x <= 2.6         Orange

2.6  < x <= 3           Red

I have used the function scatterpie in R using this data resulting in a scatterpie chart containing 10 pies, each having 3 equal pieces of the categories A, B, C. How can I obtain a scatterpie plot which reads the values from the the variables A, B and C and transforms them into the above indicated colors when we plot the scatterpie?

The code I use is as follows:

```
library(scatterpie)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

n = 10
long <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=2))
lat <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=1))
d <- data.frame(long=long, lat=lat)
d$region <- factor(1:n)
d$A <- runif(10, 1, 3)
d$B <- runif(10, 1, 3)
d$C <- runif(10, 1, 3)

d$Apiece = 1
d$Bpiece = 1
d$Cpiece = 1

head(d)

ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=region), data=d,
                       cols=c("Apiece", "Bpiece", "Cpiece")) + coord_equal()I appreciate your help!
```

Comment: I would suggest you make a new grouping variable that puts the values in its color group. Then use this variable in the `aes` as `fill` or `color` (not too sure) and use some `manual_fill` function in the end.

Comment: to make the grouping variable you can use the `cut` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used the function 'cut', but I didn't get the results I wanted. Instead, I wrote a function in order to assign the hex colors to each range for A, B and C which are then stored in the new columns d$ColorA, d$ColorB and d$ColorC. Yet, I do not achieve to apply manual_fill properly, such that the pie parts are assigned these hex colors. Could you clarify your suggestion please?

Comment: You should have one Variable for eg `color_group` add that Variable into `aes(color=color_group,...)` then add `+ scale_colour_manual()` with your distinct colors.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but only the borders obtain the correct color. Also, I end up with two legends due to the fact that it reads the 'col' variables, which are the columns containing only ones in order to arrive at equally sized pie pieces. I will post the code that I use now in the next comment!

Comment: `colours_group = c("#00B050","#92D050", "#FFFF99", "#FFC000", "#FF0000") ` and the second line is             
`ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=region, colour = cut(c(d$A, d$B, d$C), c(1, 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3.0))), data=d,
          cols=c("Apiece", "Bpiece", "Cpiece")) + 
  coord_equal()  + scale_colour_manual("Risk", values = colour_group)`